# want to find pattern with given starting and ending pattern but may contain any number of new line in that

Tags: python-3.x

Below is line that i want to extract from file, i.e starting with `<XYZ>` and ending with `</XYZ>` but there may be any number of new lines in it

```xml
<XYZ>
<beta1>aaaaa</beta1>
<beta>aaaaa</beta>
<beta0>aaaaa</beta0>
<identity>key01_adent</identity>
<beta>aaaaa</beta>
<beta>aaaaa</beta>
<beta>aaaaa</beta>
</XYZ>
```

```py
f=open('D:\\pyth_project\\policy.xml', 'r')
read_object=f.read()
f.close()
print(re.findall("<XYZ>\n+.*\n</XYZ>",read_object))
```

Comment: Use a XML parser like [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in other answers, if you are dealng wth XML sintax there are better solutions than simple regex.

But if you really want to use regex, this is how you can do it:

```
f = open('yourfile', 'r')
read_object = f.read()
f.close()
print(re.findall(r"<XYZ>.*?</XYZ>", read_object, flags=re.DOTALL))
```

The `re.DOTALL` flag allows the `.` special character to match also newlines (by default, it matches all characters except newlines).
The `*?` is the non-greedy version of `*`, matching as few characters as possible. So if you have multiple `<XYZ>...</XYZ>` tags each one will be a separate match.

The assumption here is that you don't have nested `<XYZ>...</XYZ>` tags. If you have nested tags, better use `lxml` as in @blueteeth answer.

Comment: If so, please consider to accept the answer, thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use regular expressions for XML-like files. You can use [lxml](https://lxml.de/index.html) instead.

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.parse('D:\\pyth_project\\policy.xml')
xyzs = root.findall('.//xyz') # find all xyz tags recursively.

for xyz in xyzs:
    print(etree.tostring(xyz))
```

See [How to find recursively for a tag of XML using LXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723015/how-to-find-recursively-for-a-tag-of-xml-using-lxml) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The following sample shows how to read the `key01_adent` value where `stuff` is the imaginary xml document

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

input = '''
<stuff>
    <XYZ>
      <beta1>aaaaa</beta1>
      <beta>aaaaa</beta>
      <beta0>aaaaa</beta0>
      <identity>key01_adent</identity>
      <beta>aaaaa</beta>
      <beta>aaaaa</beta>
      <beta>aaaaa</beta>
    </XYZ>
</stuff>'''

stuff = ET.fromstring(input)
lst = stuff.findall('.XYZ')
print('count:', len(lst))


for item in lst:
    print('identity = {}'.format(item.find('identity').text))
```

The `item` can have any number of items in it, i expect the tags will be unique

You can test the same [here](https://trinket.io/python3/c4f7acbb22) and play with it