# Couldn' find element in XML by tag using LXML

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

Trying to parse `data.xspf` with `Python 3.6.8` and `LXML 4.4.1` following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723015/how-to-find-recursively-for-a-tag-of-xml-using-lxml) and find `<creator>Creator</creator>` element but have `[]` output.

data.xspf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/" version="1">
  <title/>
  <creator/>
  <trackList>
    <track>
      <location>http://localhost:8000</location>
      <creator>Creator</creator>
      <title>Title</title>
      <annotation>Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah</annotation>
      <info>info</info>
    </track>
  </trackList>
</playlist>
```

Script:

```py
>>> from lxml import etree

>>> tree = etree.parse("data.xspf")
>>> tree.findall('.//creator')
```

Any idea?

Comment: In you sample the creator tag is empty (`<creator/>`).  For testing purpose you may try another node : `tree.findall('.//track')`

Comment: @Stephan, I guess this case output shoud be like ```<lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x7fe91d8592c8>``` cause the element itself is not None. The text it contains is empty. ```tree.findall('.//track')``` -- the same result

Comment: And by the way ```findall()``` should find all elements inсluding the last one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the second argument of the function to make sure the default namespace is taken into account `tree.findall('.//creator', { None : 'http://xspf.org/ns/0/' })`.